# How can I avoid app crashing because of importing jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I tried many ways of importing `jest` into my project. All of them cause my app to crash displaying the blank screen when visiting `localhost:3000` even though all statements cause app to compile (the single line of import causes the app to crash):

```
import { mocked } from "ts-jest"

import { mocked } from '@jest/globals'

import { jest } from 'ts-jest'

import { jest } from '@jest/globals'
```

App crashes with the following error:

```
VM551:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

I have the following dependency in `package.json`:

```
"ts-jest": "^28.0.7"
```

What might be the reason behind crashing? What is the correct way to import `jest`? I need specifically `mocked` object to be available, is there a right way to make it work without crashing the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to import `jest` or `mocked` into your application code that runs in the browser, which won't work. `process` is a global in Node, but not in the browser, which is why you're getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

If you're trying to use mock data, you can define that data in a separate file that you can import both in your test files (which run in Node) and in your application code (which runs in the browser).

Comment: Not sure I understand. I am trying to mock an object returned by an authentication service Auth0 as per this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60010211/react-how-to-mock-auth0-for-testing-with-jest. Does your answer mean I don’t need `jest` for it?

Comment: I think there are a couple things going on here, but it would help to see more code in your example. How and where are you trying to use `jest` or `mocked` when you import it? If it's being imported into client-side code, that would explain `process` being undefined. But if you're trying to call `jest.mock()` in a test file (similar to the question you linked), you can do that without importing `jest`. You have a `jest` global when you run tests with jest.

Comment: Yes, I am importing it into the client-side code. Not sure how to mock return by auth service in my webapp otherwise (another library or..). But I see your point now, jest is supposed to be used on backend running tests from the cmd.

Comment: If you post more of your code I can see if I can help, the mock should be in the file with your tests.