# Mocking return value of react-oidc-context in jest with typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, react-oidc-context, oidc-client-ts

In our project we are using react-oidc-context (which uses oidc-client-ts) to authenticate a user.

react-oidc-context exposes `useAuth`, which contains information like `isAuthenticated`, `isLoading`, the `user` object when authenticated, etc.

In order to fully test my components I need to mock it with different return values in each test. Normally I would do this with `jest.spyOn` and `mockImplementation` to set the right conditions for my test.

However, the number of (nested) properties that `useAuth` returns is pretty big and may be prone to change in the future, so I don't want to type everything out. I just want to pass the properties that I care about. But typescript doesn't allow that.

An example:

```
// Login.tsx
// AuthProvider has redirect_uri set that points back to this file

import { Button } from 'react-components';
import { useAuth } from 'react-oidc-context';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = (): JSX.Element => {
  const auth = useAuth();

  if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/dashboard" replace />;
  }

  return (
    <main style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', paddingTop: '5rem' }}>
      <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => auth.signinRedirect()}>
        Sign in
      </Button>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

```
// Login.test.tsx

import { renderWithProviders, screen } from '@test/utils';
import * as oidc from 'react-oidc-context';

import Login from '../Login';

describe('Login view', () => {
  it('Shows a login button', () => {
    jest.spyOn(oidc, 'useAuth').mockImplementation(
      () =>
        ({
          isAuthenticated: false,
        })
    );

    // renderWithProviders wraps the normal testing-library render with the routing provider
    renderWithProviders(<Login />);
    expect(screen.findByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' }));
  });
});
```

In the above code typescript will complain that the mockImpelmentation doesn't match AuthContextProps. And it is right! 12 direct props are missing and many more deeply nested ones.

If I try to trick TS:

```
// Login.test.tsx with type casting

import { renderWithProviders, screen } from '@test/utils';
import * as oidc from 'react-oidc-context';

import Login from '../Login';

describe('Login view', () => {
  it('Shows a login button', () => {
    jest.spyOn(oidc, 'useAuth').mockImplementation(
      () =>
        ({
          isAuthenticated: false,
        }) as oidc.AuthContextProps // <--- NEW
    );

    renderWithProviders(<Login />);
    expect(screen.findByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' }));
  });
});
```

Now I get a runtime error: `TypeError: Cannot redefine property: useAuth`

Crap.

I have tried many different mocking tricks but everything fails at some point.

Going back to the drawing board, I tried to forego the whole mocking thing and just setup a Provider with fake credentials. Basically what I do for react-router.

This will work for the unauthenticated state, but to my knowledge I can't fake the authenticated state.

```
import { renderWithProviders, screen } from '@test/utils';

import Login from '../Login';

describe('Login view', () => {
  it('Shows a login button', () => {
    renderWithProviders(
      <AuthProvider
        {...{
          authority: 'authority',
          client_id: 'client',
          redirect_uri: 'redirect',
        }}
      >
        <Login />
      </AuthProvider>
    );
    expect(screen.findByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' }));
  });
});
```

So the last thing I can think of is to write some helper to generate a big return object for `useAuth` that satisfies TS.
Like I said I've been putting it off, because this doesn't seem very future-proof.

Anyone an idea how to fix this and make it pretty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good night sleep, I finally found a way. Inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761102/1783174

```
// jest.config.ts

{
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/test/jest-setup.ts'],
}
```

In jest-setup I create the default mocked return values for `useAuth`

```
// test/jest-setup.ts

jest.mock('react-oidc-context', () => ({
  // The result of this mock can be altered by changing `mockAuthenticatedStatus` in your test
  useAuth() {
    const { isLoading, isAuthenticated } = getMockAuthStatus();
    return {
      isLoading,
      isAuthenticated,
      signinRedirect: jest.fn(),
      removeUser: jest.fn(),
      settings: {},
    };
  },
}));
```

```
// test/utils.ts

// ..in this file is also the renderWithProviders function that adds the react-router MemoryBrowser..

export const mockAuthenticatedStatus = {
  isLoading: false,
  isAuthenticated: false,
};

export const getMockAuthStatus = () => {
  return mockAuthenticatedStatus;
};
```

```
// views/__tests__/Login.test.tsx

import { mockAuthenticatedStatus, renderWithProviders, screen } from '@test/utils';
import * as router from 'react-router-dom';

import Login from '../Login';

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
  Navigate: jest.fn(),
}));

describe('Login view', () => {
  it('Shows a login button', () => {
    // BY DEFAULT WE ARE LOGGED OUT
    renderWithProviders(<Login />);
    expect(screen.findByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' }));
  });

  it('Navigates when logged in', () => {
    // HERE WE CHANGE THE AUTH STATUS FOR THIS TEST
    mockAuthenticatedStatus.isAuthenticated = true;
    const navigateSpy = jest.spyOn(router, 'Navigate');
    renderWithProviders(<Login />);
    expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

For reference, here is the Login component file that we tested

```
// views/Login.tsx

import { Button } from 'react-components';
import { useAuth } from 'react-oidc-context';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { signIn } from '../auth/utils';

const Login = (): JSX.Element => {
  const auth = useAuth();

  if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
  }

  return (
    <main style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', paddingTop: '5rem' }}>
      <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => signIn(auth)}>
        Sign in
      </Button>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: Any ideas to mock <AuthenticationContext.Consumer> from react-oidc-context? All things I've tried so far resulted in "Element type is invalid" render errors.